# Can't connect to Python/Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am trying to start a Project with Gmail API using Python on one of our local servers.
I was able to download/install latest Python and run basic Hello World Scripts.

I am trying to link a GMAIL Project with it, and using GMAIL API, but unfortunately any credentials JSON file I download doesn't seem to pull the credentials for the project.

I created OAUTH 2.0 and Service account JSON file. Both do not work.

I either get one of the following errors:

For Service account JSON file - ValueError("Client secrets must be for a web or installed app

For OAuth 2.0 Desktop app Credentials File - "ValueError: Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields token_uri, client_email."

Any insight into this?

I am following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfeKF1zgwj0&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJJFx_MVCQJ7eWF3gDxklgJ

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246214/how-to-create-a-signature-for-primary-gusite-account-using-gmail-api-using-the-s/61247996#61247996) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61032222/google-apis-requests-requesterror-404-error-when-using-gmail-api-to-change-sig/61058809#61058809) help?

Comment: Your question title _"Create Dynamic Signature using Python/Gmail API"_ has nothing to do with your problem(s): 1. _"but unfortunately any credentials JSON file I download doesn't seem to pull the credentials for the project."_ 2. _"I created OAUTH 2.0 and Service account JSON file. Both do not work."_ I'm updating the title to "Can't connect to gmail API".